# mySQL - Display 0 when no entry.

Tags: mysql

I have searched but no positive results on this issue hence the question. I am writing a query and want the missing values to be represented as 0

My table looks like

id ---- requesteddate ---- pillar ---- status

1 -----12/31/2013------IT-------6

2-----1/1/2014---------IT-------6

3-----1/30/2014--------HR-------7

The result I am trying to get is

2013 -- IT -- 2

2013 -- HR -- 0

2014 -- IT -- 1

2014 -- HR -- 1

I cannot the HR 0 to show up. I have tried COALESCE(count(`id`), 0) and creating the group as a sub and joining it with no success. Please help!

Comment: This does not work - select distinct w.`pillar`, 0 AS count, sub.count, sub.year FROM `witrequest` w
left join
 (SELECT 
 CONVERT(concat(id,projectid), CHAR(255)) as Id,
 YEAR(`requesteddate`) as year, 
 `pillar` as pillar, 
 count(`id`) AS count
 FROM `witrequest`
 where `status` > 5  
 group by YEAR(`requesteddate`) ,`pillar`) sub 
on w.pillar = sub.pillar

Comment: This does not work either - SELECT 
CONVERT(concat(id,projectid), CHAR(255)) as Id,
YEAR(`requesteddate`) as year, 
`pillar` as pillar, 
COALESCE(count(`id`), 0) as cnt, 
IF(count(`id`) IS NULL, 0, count(`id`)) AS count
FROM `witrequest`
where `status` > 5
group by YEAR(`requesteddate`),`pillar`

Comment: The fundamental problem: one can't SELECT something that *doesn't exist*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CROSS JOIN to get a combination of all years/pillars, and then a LEFT JOIN that will return all combinations of years/pillars and only the requests that match. If a combination of year/pillar is not present, witrequest.id will be null and it won't be counted:

```
SELECT years.`year`, pillars.pillar, COUNT(witrequest.id)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(requesteddate) AS `year`
   FROM witrequest) years
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT pillar
   FROM witrequest) pillars
  LEFT JOIN witrequest
  ON YEAR(witrequest.requesteddate)=years.`year`
     AND witrequest.pillar=pillars.pillar
GROUP BY
  years.`year`, pillars.pillar
```